# How can I call a block method from a script file?

Tags: blocks, script

I'm running a script off my root directory, `http://www.example.com/my_script.php`.

Within this script, I am trying to call a function from `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Abstract`:

```
public function getPriceHtml($product, $displayMinimalPrice = false, $idSuffix = '')
{
    $type_id = $product->getTypeId();
    if (Mage::helper('catalog')->canApplyMsrp($product)) {
        $realPriceHtml = $this->_preparePriceRenderer($type_id)
            ->setProduct($product)
            ->setDisplayMinimalPrice($displayMinimalPrice)
            ->setIdSuffix($idSuffix)
            ->toHtml();
        $product->setAddToCartUrl($this->getAddToCartUrl($product));
        $product->setRealPriceHtml($realPriceHtml);
        $type_id = $this->_mapRenderer;
    }

    return $this->_preparePriceRenderer($type_id)
        ->setProduct($product)
        ->setDisplayMinimalPrice($displayMinimalPrice)
        ->setIdSuffix($idSuffix)
        ->toHtml();
}
```

How can I call `Mage::Catalog_Block_Product_Abstract::getPriceHtml` from within my script file? I've tried:

1. Creating an object using Mage::getBlockSingleton('catalog/product_abstract')->getPriceHtml

Which results in this error:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function getPriceHtml() on a non-object
```

2. Class inclusion

Like this:

```
include('../app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/Abstract.php');
$catalog_block = new Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Abstract();
```

Which results in:

```
Fatal error: Cannot instantiate abstract class Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Abstract
```

Because it is an abstract class.

Is it possible for me to do this somehow?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Abstract` is abstract so it cannot be instantiated.
But you can use one of its child classes.  For example `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View`.

You can try this:

```
Mage::app()->getLayout()->createBlock('catalog/product_view')->getPriceHtml(....)
```

Comment: Hmm. `Mage::getBlockSingleton('catalog/product_view')->getPriceHtml($_product, true);` still gives me the `non-object` error.

Comment: It might, but on what method call?

Comment: On the `->getPriceHtml()` method

Comment: I've edited the answer. Try with `createBlock`

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you. #Heil Marius!